# How to find owner and group of a directory?

Tags: permissions, files

How can I find out owner and group of a directory in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 299, accepted):

You can do this:
1st way:

```
ls -l /path/to/file
```

*the third field in the ls -l output is the user and the fourth is the group

2nd way:

**stat /path/to/file**

```
$ stat py
  File: `py'
  Size: 32              Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d      Inode: 429064      Links: 1
Access: (0777/-rwxrwxrwx)  Uid: ( 1000/  razvan)   Gid: ( 1000/  razvan)
Access: 2012-07-27 17:49:05.682143441 +0300
Modify: 2012-07-01 03:58:02.848540175 +0300
Change: 2012-08-01 21:12:57.129819212 +0300
```

The razvan in the Uid field is the owner/user, the razvan in the Gid field is the group. 8-|

3rd way:
Get only the user and group with stat:

```
stat -c "%U %G" /path/to/file
```

Comment: The default bashrc in ubuntu aliases `ll` to `ls -l`

Comment: As a heads up this is for GNU stat, specific to ubuntu this works, but looking for a portable (BSD supported solution) this is not the answer for you.

Comment: FWIW, on BSD (mac) this would be `stat -f "%u %g" /path/to/file`

Comment: WARNING: "stat" returns the string "UNKNOWN" for %U and %G if it is not defined in the system files. While "ls" will return the UID/GID if unknown. It is better to work with UID (%u) and GID (%g) numbers from "stat" if possible.

Comment: Do not parse `ls`. More info: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/133353

Comment: +1 for the part about `stat`, not about `ls`

Answer (score 33):

Run [`ls`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/ls.1.html) with the `-l` flag to show the owner and group-owner of files and directories in the current directory (or in a specific named directory).

```
~$ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x  2 owner group 4096 Aug 12 19:12 Desktop
...
```

```
~$ ls -l /home/username
drwxr-xr-x  2 owner group 4096 Aug 12 19:12 Desktop
...
```

Run `ls` with the `-l` and `-d` flags to show this information about the current directory itself (or about a specific named directory):

```
~$ ls -ld
drwxr-xr-x  2 owner group 4096 Aug 12 19:12 .
```

```
~$ ls -ld ~/Desktop
drwxr-xr-x  2 owner group 4096 Aug 12 19:12 Desktop
```

Answer (score 26):

To get the owner and group of a directory you need

```
ls -ld /path/to/folder
```

Otherwise you get the attributes of the contents of the directory.

Answer (score 5):

In Nautilus (the GUI file manager)

- Find the folder corresponding to the directory
- Right click it.
- Select Properties
- Select the Permissions Tab

Providing you have the permission to change the permissions you can change them from that window, too.

Answer (score 2):

My subtle way

```
ls -alF /path/to/folder | grep -Ei ' ./'
```

sample output

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 some-user some-group 4096 Feb 28 02:29 ./
```

Comment: Of course shorter way still to be `stat /path/to/folder` command

Comment: Do not parse `ls`. More info: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/133353

Comment: I don't agrree why we cannot parse `ls` result