# Why are "ls" and "stat" returning different ownerships for the same object?

Tags: command-line, ls, chown

This is in a continuation of question [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/175054/78079)

I run this command as root user

```
chown someuser:someuser /mnt/my-address
```

and then

```
# ls -l /mnt/my-address
```

response is

```
total 16
drwx------ 2 root root 16384 Aug 16 11:04 lost+found
```

but when i do

```
stat /mnt/my-address
```

and response is

```
File: `/mnt/my-address'
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: ca51h/51793d    Inode: 2           Links: 3
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (  106/ someuser)   Gid: (  112/ someuser)
Access: 2012-08-16 13:59:53.261099055 +0000
Modify: 2012-08-16 11:04:45.000000000 +0000
Change: 2012-08-16 13:59:44.013099226 +0000
 Birth: -
```

Why I am getting difference user and group with different commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ls -l /mnt/my-address` is showing you the files/directories *inside* `my-address`. These are only affected if you use the `chown -R` command to change ownership (R)ecursively. All you did was change the ownership of `/mnt/my-address`, not any of its contents.

`stat /mnt/my-address` gives you information on the actual directory/mountpoint `/mnt/my-address` though, whose ownership you *did* change. That's why the two are different.

Comment: +1, recursively means all the files and directory inside of `/mnt/my-address`

Comment: Thanks, I wrote the answer on my phone, edited to clarify.