# Access denied to delete file

Tags: permissions, files

I moved my files from Windows 7 PC to another Ubuntu 16.1 PC over LAN cable.

Now when I try to delete my files in the Ubuntu PC it says access denied?

```
total 28
-rwxr--r--  1 nobody nogroup  889 Jun 16  2016 Android Book Links.txt
-rwxr--r--  1 nobody nogroup    0 Mar  7  2009 AUTOEXEC.BAT
drwxr-xr-x  2 nobody nogroup 4096 Mar 11 03:22 Book
-rwxr--r--  1 nobody nogroup    0 Mar  7  2009 CONFIG.SYS
drwxr-xr-x  6 nobody nogroup 4096 Mar 11 03:33 Documents and Settings
drwxr-xr-x  2 nobody nogroup 4096 Mar 11 03:33 i386
drwxr-xr-x 13 nobody nogroup 4096 Mar 12 09:59 My Documents
drwxr-xr-x 11 nobody nogroup 4096 Mar 11 23:25 TCWIN45
drwxr-xr-x  3 nobody nogroup 4096 Mar 11 23:25 VALUEADD
```

[image]

Comment: Can you open a terminal in the folder with the files and post the result of `ls -l`? How did you copy the files? They probably have the wrong owner.

Comment: If you didn't understand @SethosII comment, go to the folder which contains the files you want to delete, right click and select open in terminal option, then type `ls -l` in terminal and you'll get an output, [update your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/912936/edit) with that output

Comment: @Sethos I selected my files from my Windows PC, then I CUT them and open the folder of the Ubuntu PC from the Windows PC using Windows file explorer and paste it into the drive of the Ubuntu PC by the help of LAN cable. It has some kind of Owner issue

Comment: @Anant_infinity yes it can be, update your question with the output of `ls -l`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/175083/665251 you can even see the permission using gui

Comment: Please see now I have added the output of ls -l

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I would highly suggest you read our [tour] in order to get a better idea of how our site operates (and to get a free badge). We hope to see you around!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linux's permissions system is very different from that of Windows. For a crash course, each permission has a few facets assigned to it. Namely, there are three octal bits (`u`, `g`, and `o`) that control who can access the file and to what degree. There is also a concept called a file "owner", which is a pair of a user and a group that has control over a single file (and are controlled by the `u` and `g` bits). For a more detailed look into how Linux permissions work, check out this [excellent writeup](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes) over on the Arch Wiki.

In your case, the files are owned by the `nobody` user and the `nogroup` group, and the permissions are set such that the `nobody` user can read, write, and execute files while the `nogroup` group can only read and execute. Similarly, everyone else can only read or execute the files.

That said, there are about three solutions to this problem. You can become the `nobody` user, you can become `root`, or you can change ownership of these files. The first one is really not recommended, as the `nobody` user is a special account that shouldn't really get used.

If you just want to delete the files and be done with it, you're going to need to use the terminal. Just run the below command to delete any specific file:

```
sudo rm /path/to/file/you/want/gone
```

If you want to delete a folder, you need to use a different command:

```
sudo rm -rf /path/to/the/folder/you/want/gone
```

Before pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, make sure your command is free of typos or other errors. These commands are very dangerous, and can have unintended side effects if a command is typed improperly.

Alternatively (and probably the better way), you can take ownership of the files, giving you full control over them. Linux has something called the `chown` command for exactly this purpose. I'd assume you want to change the ownership of everything, so use this command:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /path/to/your/folder
```

If you only want to change the ownership of a single file, it's this command:

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER /path/to/your/file
```

For more information into how `chown` works, run the `man chown` command in your terminal to pull up its manual. Once again, be very careful with typographical errors -- they can and will bite you in unexpected ways.

Comment: Commands that operate on *folders* are particularly *dangerous:* `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /path/to/your/folder` ; `sudo rm -rf /path/to/the/folder/you/want/gone`

Comment: Thanks, I will try to change the ownership and see what happens will let you know then.

Comment: I really worked I changed the ownership of the folder

Comment: I dont have root access. But I want to remove the folder owned by nobody. so, How to change the owner using normal user login or else suggest any other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Open up a terminal window and use the following command:

```
sudo rm /path/to/the/file.txt
```

where  /path/to/the/ is the file path and file.txt is the file to be deleted.

You will be asked to enter your password and the file will be deleted.